# Proving that if $M$ is a simple module, then any simple submodules of $M^n$ are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be a simple module. Prove that all simple submodules of $M^n$ are isomorphic.

I think this is inferred directly by Krull-Schmidt theorem which is stated as follows:

> Let $M$ be a $R$-module and let $M\cong U_1\oplus\cdots\oplus U_m\cong V_1\oplus\cdots\oplus V_n$ be two decompositions of $M$ in which $U_i$'s and $V_j$'s are simple $R$-modules. Then, $m=n$ and after a rearrangement of indices we have $U_i\cong V_i$ for each $i$.

Assume $A$ is a simple submodule of $M^n$. Since $M^n=M\oplus\cdots\oplus M$ and $M$ is a simple module, $M^n$ is a semisimple module. Then, $M^n=A\oplus B_1\oplus\cdots\oplus B_k$. Therefore, $A\cong M$. I would like to ask if such an argument is right.

Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your proof to work, you will also need to show that every simple submodule of $M^n$ is also a direct summand. While this is true, it requires more  knowledge than just Krull-Schmidt.

I suggest you consider the projection maps $\pi_i : M^n \to M$. If $S \subseteq M$ is a simple submodule, then $\pi_i(S) \neq 0$ for some $i$. Conclude that $\pi_i$ restricts to an isomorphism $S \cong M$. This way, your proof only requires the definition of simple module.

Comment: Please tell me why if $S\subseteq M$ is a simple submodule, then $\pi_i(S)\neq0$ for some $i$ @Mathias Klipsch.

Comment: $S$ contains some nonzero element $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, and if $x_i\neq0$, then $\pi_i(x)=x_i\neq0$.